# Get items and dates checked in and out by person

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2012, how do I return a single row per person, per item for a single continuous time period when multiple check-in's are done?

We have 3 tables: Person,

```
Id, Fullname
```

Relationship

```
PersonId, ItemId, DateTime
```

Item

```
Id, ItemName
```

The relationship table is updated whenever a person does a check in with the items they have on hand.

I can join the three tables to retrieve all results but what I'm after is the following results:

Fullname, Item, Checkin, CheckOut
eg

```
Person1, Item1, 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000, 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000
Person1, Item2, 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000, 2016-10-26 20:00:00.000
Person1, Item2, 2016-10-28 20:00:00.000, 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000
Person1, Item3, 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000, 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000
...
...
```

Note 'Person1' is missing 'Item2' on the '2016-10-27 20:00:00.000' so there are two entries for 'Person1', 'Item2' for each time period because 'Person1' did a check-in on the 27th without 'Item2'

Here's the tSQL code to create the tables.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Person', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#Person
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Relationship', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#Relationship
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Item', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#Item

CREATE TABLE #Person(
Id int IDENTITY,
Fullname nvarchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE #Relationship(
Id int IDENTITY,
PersonId int,
ItemId int,
DateTime datetime
);


CREATE TABLE #Item(
Id int IDENTITY,
ItemName nvarchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO #Person (Fullname) 
VALUES ('Person1'),
('Person2'),
('Person3');

INSERT INTO #Item (ItemName) VALUES
('Item1'),
('Item2'),
('Item3');

INSERT INTO #Relationship (PersonId, ItemId, DateTime) VALUES
(1, 1, '2016-10-25 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 2, '2016-10-25 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 3, '2016-10-25 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 1, '2016-10-26 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 2, '2016-10-26 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 3, '2016-10-26 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 1, '2016-10-27 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 3, '2016-10-27 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 1, '2016-10-28 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 2, '2016-10-28 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 3, '2016-10-28 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 1, '2016-10-29 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 2, '2016-10-29 20:00:00.000'),
(1, 3, '2016-10-29 20:00:00.000'),

(2, 1, '2016-10-25 20:00:00.000'),
(2, 2, '2016-10-25 20:00:00.000'),
(2, 3, '2016-10-25 20:00:00.000'),
(2, 1, '2016-10-26 20:00:00.000'),
(2, 2, '2016-10-26 20:00:00.000'),
(2, 3, '2016-10-26 20:00:00.000'),
(2, 1, '2016-10-27 20:00:00.000'),
(2, 2, '2016-10-27 20:00:00.000'),
(2, 3, '2016-10-27 20:00:00.000');



SELECT  P.FullName, I.ItemName, R.DateTime As CheckInDate FROM #Person AS P
INNER JOIN #Relationship AS R ON R.PersonId = P.Id
INNER JOIN #Item AS I ON I.Id = R.ItemId
```

Thanks for any help or tips to find a solution!

Edit: I could return all results and process RBAR in C# but I was hoping for an elegant SQL solution. What are your thoughts?

Comment: So you want to `GROUP BY` fullname and itemname and get the `MIN` and `MAX` dates?

Comment: I played with both using

`MIN(R.DateTime) OVER () AS CheckInDate, MAX(R.DateTime) OVER () AS CheckOutDate`

it but still couldn't get it to split the rows when a checkin occured without a particular item.

Comment: The `LEAD` and `LAG` functions will allow you to get a previous/next value in your set. Alternative you can solve this using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT 
        r1.*,
        DATEDIFF(d, r1.[DateTime], LEAD(r1.[DateTime]) OVER(PARTITION BY r1.PersonId, r1.ItemId ORDER BY r1.[DateTime] ASC)) ddiff_next,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY r1.PersonId, r1.ItemId ORDER BY r1.[DateTime] ASC) rn
    FROM 
        #Relationship r1
    LEFT JOIN
        #Relationship r2 ON r1.PersonId = r2.PersonId AND r1.ItemId = r2.ItemId AND r1.[DateTime] = DATEADD(d, -1, r2.[DateTime])
    LEFT JOIN
        #Relationship r3 ON r1.PersonId = r3.PersonId AND r1.ItemId = r3.ItemId AND r1.[DateTime] = DATEADD(d, 1, r3.[DateTime])
    WHERE
        -- get the intervals' first and last rows, ie filter the rows
        -- where the date difference between it's and the next or preceding      
        -- row's dates greater than one day, or does not exists (first or
        -- last row
        r2.[DateTime] IS NULL OR r3.[DateTime] IS NULL
)

SELECT
    p.FullName,
    i.ItemName,
    t1.[DateTime] AS DateFrom,
    t2.[DateTime] AS DateTo
FROM
    temp t1
LEFT JOIN 
    temp t2 ON t1.rn = (t2.rn - 1) AND t1.PersonId = t2.PersonId AND t1.ItemId = t2.ItemId
INNER JOIN 
    #Item AS i ON i.Id = t1.ItemId
INNER JOIN 
    #Person AS p ON p.Id = t1.PersonId
WHERE
    -- exclude the gaps 
    (t1.ddiff_next IS NOT NULL AND t2.ddiff_next IS NULL)
    OR (t1.ddiff_next IS NOT NULL AND t2.ddiff_next IS NOT NULL AND t2.ddiff_next > 1)
;
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| FullName | ItemName |        DateFrom         |         DateTo          |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Person1  | Item1    | 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 | 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000 |
| Person1  | Item2    | 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 | 2016-10-26 20:00:00.000 |
| Person1  | Item2    | 2016-10-28 20:00:00.000 | 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000 |
| Person1  | Item3    | 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 | 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000 |
| Person2  | Item1    | 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 | 2016-10-27 20:00:00.000 |
| Person2  | Item2    | 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 | 2016-10-27 20:00:00.000 |
| Person2  | Item3    | 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 | 2016-10-27 20:00:00.000 |
+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: (How do I put newline in a comment? my reply looks silly) That query doesn't return two entries when 'Person1' doesn't have 'Item2'

`Person1 Item1 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000`
`Person1 Item2 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000 `
`Person1 Item3 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 2016-10-29 20:00:00.000`
`Person2 Item1 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 2016-10-27 20:00:00.000`
`Person2 Item2 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 2016-10-27 20:00:00.000`
`Person2 Item3 2016-10-25 20:00:00.000 2016-10-27 20:00:00.000`

Comment: That works perfect, thank you. I stepped through the query and understand how it works in and after the CTE. Can I ask how you broke down the problem into the individual smaller components and came up with the steps necessary? I'd love to do some more SQL learning.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! At now I don't have much time, but at the weekend I will try to write about my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Does some like below give you the desired results? You may need to adjust your JOINS to suit if data can be missing

```
   SELECT
        *
    ,   LAG(R.DateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY R.PersonId, R.ItemId
            ORDER BY R.DateTime) AS NextDatetime
    ,   LEAD(R.DateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY R.PersonId, R.ItemId
            ORDER BY R.DateTime) AS PreviousDatetime

    FROM
        #Person AS P
        JOIN #Relationship AS R
            ON  P.Id = R.PersonId
        JOIN #Item AS I
            ON  R.ItemId = I.Id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c01c/4

Comment: Great reply, I didn't know about LAG and LEAD. Now I'll try building on this to give a contiguous period until it hits a NULL. Thanks!

Comment: It depends what you mean by continuous period, I think you mean one day? This sounds like a gaps and islands problem, there is a very good PDF you can read on the problem and solution https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/e589652-7171-4310-a714-e84dd0f14090/SampleChapter5.pdf

Comment: An analogy is like an employment period. Worker X did 10 consecutive days of work, then 5 consecutive days off, then 10 consecutive days of work There's a record for each day of work and I want a date from and date to for each uninterrupted period so this query would return 2 rows. I'm having trouble explaining it.
I'll read the PDF now, thanks again